# Sorting a list of sObjects

Tags: wrapper-class

I have parent and child objects. now i want to perform sorting in child records list so Kindly suggest me how is it's possible.

currently i am using wrapper class in which i have used "sobject" refers to parent records and  "`List<toDisplay> children`" refer to Child Records list under parent records.

```
 public class toDisplay {
            public Boolean isFirstObj {get; set;}
            public sObject sObj {get; set;}
            public String objId {get; set;}
            public List<toDisplay> children {get; set;}
             public Boolean toggleEditSave {get; set;}
             public toDisplay(){
                this.toggleEditSave=false;
            }
        } // End wrapper class
```

Comment: You can simply use order by clause to sort the list while querying the records

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possibilities to sort a list of sObjects. The first and easiest one is a use of the `sort()` method of the List class. Next one is a bit tricky and it is a `Comparable interface`.

### List.sort()

If you have a *list of sObjects* you can use a standard method `sort()`.

> The List.sort method sorts sObjects in ascending order and compares
>   sObjects using an ordered sequence of steps that specify the labels or
>   fields used.

Assumed your list is a list of sObjects, it would be like this in that case:

```
children.sort();
```

It is easy to use but you have almost no way to controll the sort process.
Here you can read about sorting: [Sorting Lists of sObjects](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm)

### Comparable Interface

If you wish to have more flexible and powerful sort algorythm you can use a comparable interface. It adds a custom sort order to the list of sObjects (or other non-primitive types).

> Alternatively, you can also implement a custom sort order for sObjects
>   by wrapping your sObject in an Apex class and implementing the
>   Comparable interface

So the interface takes two list elements and compares based on some critera defined by you. And this is realy powerful. In the next example I'll use a field of the sObject as a comparison criteria.

```
public class ChildObject implements Comparable {
    public child Child__c { get; set; }

    public ChildObject(Child__c child) {
        this.child = child;
    }

    // This method returns an integer, that is the result of the comparison
    public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        // Defining comparison object
        // child          - is a first object for compare
        // compareToChild - is a next element of the list
        ChildObject compareToChild = (ChildObject)compareTo;

        // Now we can compare two child objects to each other 
        // basen on every sObject field
        if(child.SomeSortField__c > compareToChild.SomeSortField__c) {
            returnValue = 1;
        }
        else {
            returnValue = -1;
        }
    }
}

// Creating a list of child objects
List<ChildObject> myList = new List<ChildObject>();

for(Child__c child : [Select Id, SomeSortField__c From Child__c]) {
    myList.add(child);
}

// And finally sorting a list of sObjects.
// At this point the comparable interface will sort our list.
myList.sort();
```

Here an official doc:

- [Custom Sort Order of sObjects](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm#CustomSortSection)
- [Comparable Interface: Class and Methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_comparable.htm)

Now it is up to you which option you will take. I would propose to implement an comparable interface. It is cool, powerfull and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [utility class](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/apex-sort-sobs) to help with sorting SObjects lists.  It supports traversal of multiple parents.

Sort on Field:

```
Account[] accs = [SELECT My_Custom_Field__c FROM Account LIMIT 2000];
SortSobs.ascending(accs, Account.My_Custom_Field__c);
```

Sort on parent(s) field:

```
List<Contact> entries = [SELECT Name, Account.Name FROM Contact limit 2000];
SortSobs.ascending(entries, SObjectField[]{ Contact.Account, Account.Name });
```

If performance is critical, I would be careful using this (ex: in triggers on core objects).